# Splitting String by multiple symbols,regex

Tags: java, regex

Regex split through multiple symbols `String s="He is a very very good boy, isn't he?"`

```
String[] sa = s.split("[!, ?._'@]");
System.out.println(sa.length);
for (String string : sa) {
    System.out.println(string);
}

11
He
is
a
very
very
good
boy

isn
t
he
```

while using

```
String[] sa = s.split("[!, ?._'@]+");

10
He
is
a
very
very
good
boy
isn
t
he
```

`+` in regex ie used for one or more but how this space is coming?

Comment: What do you expect for ", "? Your input has a literal comma followed by a literal space. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Perhaps he wants to know why the result of the 1st split has a space also and not the 2nd. This account for the length to be 10 instead of 11.

Comment: I want to split the sentence with special characters and in output I want words only ...no spaces as its there in first case....I know I am using space for split ....but if I will not use space how will I get the tokens(words) and no of words

Comment: This is the question exactly -Given a string, s, matching the regular expression [A-Za-z !,?._'@]+, split the string into tokens. We define a token to be one or more consecutive English alphabetic letters. Then, print the number of tokens, followed by each token on a new line.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/nO8v6m

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the `split` function is creating an array element containing an empty string between the comma `,` and the space  after *boy*.

```
arr = ['He', 'is', 'a', 'very', 'very', 'good', 'boy', '', 'isn', 't', 'he']
```

The function beleives there is some text between the comma and the space when it splits the text, effectively generating that empty string.

When you use the `+` symbol, you split by "groups" of characters, and it takes the comma and space as the splitting regular expression, not generating that empty string between those characters.